# Is it correct to say that data reading operations need not run inside transactions?

Tags: database, transactions, acid

Say that a method only reads data from a database and does not write to it. Is it always the case that such methods don't need to run within a transaction?

Comment: My answer: Yes. However, the folks at [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) would be better suited for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you don't read at a specific isolation level you might not get enough guarantees. For example rows might disappear or new rows might appear.

This is true even for a single statement:

```
select * from Tab
except select * from Tab
```

This query can actually return rows in case of concurrent modifications because it scans the table twice.

SQL Server: There is an easy way to get fast, nonblocking, nonlocking, consistent reads: Enable snapshot isolation and read in a snapshot transaction. AFAIK Oracle has this capability as well. Postgres too.

Answer (score 2):

In many databases a request for reading from the database which is not in an explicit transaction implicitly creates a transaction to run the request.

In a SQL database you may want to use a transaction if you are running multiple `SELECT` statements and you don't want changes from other transactions to show up in one `SELECT` but not an earlier one.  A transaction running at the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level will present a consistent view of the data across multiple statements.

Comment: REPEATABLE READ is not consistent as new rows may appear.

Comment: You're right. I'll fix the answer. Thanks. (In PostgreSQL REPEATABLE READ is enough, because you get Snapshot Isolation, but this wasn't a PostgreSQL question, so the answer should give the portable answer.)

Answer (score 0):

the purpose of transaction is to rollback or commit the operations done to a database, if u are just selecting values and making no change in the data there is no need of transaction.

Comment: Wrong. Transactions can also provide a consistent view of the data.

Comment: @usr A select statement should not use a transaction.  It's entirely pointless, when you commit the transaction you will not commit anything (since nothing changed) and therefore you will only incur the overhead of establishing the transaction. 

transactions are simply used to maintain valid data.  So that if you change one table and another table depends on it you will not update one table without updating the other.  If the second update fails the first update would be rolled back to it's original state.  If both are successful then you can commit both together and ensure valid data.
contd.

Comment: So in other words, you only need transactiosn when doing inserts/updates/deletes and only when performing multiple operations.

Comment: no, see my answer. Even a single statement needs to be hardened against various inconsistencies caused by concurrent activity. In your mind, transactions are only about atomicity. They are also about isolation.